# Do Modern Optimization Algorithms "Ignore" Duality?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

In traditional optimization problems, the idea of "duality" was of great importance - from a Linear Programming perspective, "duality" allows us to potentially simplify solving complicated constraint optimization problems by converting them into a different form.

**My Question:** **As advancements in computers have taken place over the years, have we begun to "ignore" the "duality" concept in optimization problems?**

For example, in the context of Machine Learning - to prevent Machine Learning models from "Overfitting", sometimes we add a L1-Norm or an L2-Norm "penalty constraint" to the objective function (corresponding to the machine learning model) we are trying to optimize. This is referred to as "Regularization":

[image]

In these cases, the regularization penalty terms are added to the objective function, and the objective function is then **directly** (without exploring "duality") optimized using (some variant of the) Gradient Descent Algorithm:

[image]

**Thus, it would appear as though nowadays we are less interested in studying the "duality" aspect of the optimization problem, and we are directly optimizing the objective function using powerful computers and Gradient Descent.**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is an unconstrained problem.  What duality aspect do you feel is being ignored?

Comment: @ Michael: thank you for your reply! Wouldnt the "lambda terms" be considered as a constraint?

Comment: There are no explicit constraints here, but if we think of $\lambda\geq 0$ as a "Lagrange multiplier" then (regardless of convexity/non-convexity of $f, g$) minimizing $f(x) + \lambda g(x)$ yields a result $x^*$ that is also a solution to the constrained problem of minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)\leq g(x^*)$.  The proof is 1-2 lines but you can think of it as a duality concept.

Comment: @ Michael: Thank you so much!